# IBP of an integral gives me different results, depending on how I approach it

Tags: integration

For the integral
$$I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x\cos(kx)dx$$
I can note that this is an odd function, so I can conclude that $I = 0$.
But, if I were to approach it via IBP, it seems to give me a different answer.
letting $u = x, dv = \cos kx dx \implies du = dx, v = \frac{1}{k}\sin kx$.

Then
$$I = 0 - \frac{2}{k} \int_0^\pi \sin kx dx \\ = \frac{2}{k}\left[ \cos k x\right]_{0}^{\pi} \\ = \frac{2}{k} (\cos k\pi - 1) \\ = \frac{2}{k} ((-1)^k - 1)$$
which is not always zero, as what the integral should be. Did I made some careless mistake, I looked over it already a few times...

Comment: Where did the $2$ come from? Should it not be $-\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(kx)\;dx$?

Comment: @carmichael561 Zzz, a fresh pair of eyes is always better. I think I should take a break... thanks!!!

Comment: If you do not find zero, be sure you made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear this up, carmichael561 is correct. After applying integration by parts you should obtain
$$\left(x \frac{\sin(kx)}{k} \right)\bigg|_{-\pi}^{\pi}-\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(kx)\;dx = 0 -\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2}\bigg|_{-\pi}^{\pi}=0$$
At this point, or earlier, it looks like you acted as if either $x\cos(kx)$ or $\sin(kx)$ was an even function and split it up accordingly, but instead both are odd, so that's probably where you made your mistake.